# Making new variable through mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make a new variable "churned" by taking into account five variables :

1. Include in churn
2. A-Churn
3. B-Churn
4. C-Churn
5. D-Churn

My condition is - If variable "Include in churn" has 1 and for all other variables , if any one of the variables has 1 than my new variable "Churned" should have 1 else 0. I am a newbie in using mutate function.

Please help me to create this new variable thru 'mutate' function.

Comment: Please show some data : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It sounds like you want to nest an `ifelse()` function within `mutate()` access their help docs by submitting `?ifelse`  or `?mutate` to the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your formulation logically, you want

```
mutate(data, Churned = Include.in.Churn == 1 & (A.Churn == 1 | B.Churn == 1 | C.Churn == 1 | D.Churn == 1))
```

This will make `Churned` a logical. If you really need an integer, `as.integer` will produce `1` for `TRUE` and `0` for `FALSE`.

If all mentioned Variables are either `1` or `0` you can also use the possibly faster

```
mutate(data, Churned = Include.in.Churn * (A.Churn + B.Churn + C.Churn + D.Churn) >= 1)
```